# Using xargs to copy files from local system into docker container

Tags: linux, docker, xargs

I have a folder with about 8000 images named like this `img_991_990_0_drawing.jpg.jpg`. I want to copy all files from my local system into a docker container.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Docker: 18.09.2

I tried `sudo docker cp <source_path> <container_id>:<dest_path>` and ran into `sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/docker: Argument list too long`.

So I tried to copy all files with `xargs` the following way `find /data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/* | xargs /bin/cp 1f17d5044287:/home/dataturks/bazaar/uploads/2c91808274774ae60/`

But I will get the not a directory error

```
/bin/cp: target '/data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/img_2585_2581_0_drawing.jpg.jpg' is not a directory
/bin/cp: target '/data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/img_4076_4070_0_drawing.jpg.jpg' is not a directory
/bin/cp: target '/data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/img_5570_5560_0_drawing.jpg.jpg' is not a directory
/bin/cp: target '/data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/img_7052_7040_0_drawing.jpg.jpg' is not a directory
/bin/cp: target '/data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/img_999_998_0_drawing.jpg.jpg' is not a directory
```

I usually can use `cp` for copying my files, so I never used `xargs` in the past. I think I´m missing an option.

If you wonder why I want to copy a buch of images rather than one folder, I am working with DataTurks and I need the files in `/bazaar/uploads/2c91808274774ae60` to have access to them via localhost.

Comment: Try passing `-l` to xargs. Does that work?

Comment: Can you use a `docker run -v` bind mount option to inject the whole directory at container startup time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
find /data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/ -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -iIMG docker cp IMG 1f17d5044287:/home/dataturks/bazaar/uploads/2c91808274774ae60/
```

First, you were using `/bin/cp` in your example, rather than `docker cp`.

Secondly, when you have an `xargs` command that looks like `xargs <cmd> <arg1>`, this will produce commands of the form `<cmd> <arg1> arg arg arg ...`. To get the correct syntax for `docker cp`, you need to use the `-i` option to define a replacement string, and then insert that in the appropriate place in the command (because the destination directory needs to be the last argument).

The `-print0` for find and the `-0` for `xargs` are just there for the sake of correctness; they will allow things to work if you have filenames that contain whitespace.

---

As an alternative, consider just using `tar` instead:

```
tar -C /data/projects/cad-detection/darknet/result_img/ -cf- . |
docker exec -i 1f17d5044287 tar -C /home/dataturks/bazaar/uploads/2c91808274774ae60/ -xf-
```

Of course, this requires that `tar` is installed in your container.